# ROC -chart in r -margin too high

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, roc

I am trying to create plot for roc but get the message :

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

tried `par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))` but with no success

the data is from kaggle: bank-full.csv (Ensemble Techniques) -
or see below reproducible code (with data):

```
   library(gmodels)
    #install.packages("tidyverse")
    library(tidyverse)
    #install.packages("C50")
    require(C50)
    #install.packages("ggplot2")
    require(ggplot2)
    #install.packages("corrplot")
    library(corrplot)
    #install.packages("corrgram")
    library(corrgram)
    setwd("C:/R_homework/R_project/potential_projects")
    library(class)
    library(rpart)
    library(caret)
    library(rpart.plot)
    
    bank_data2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      age = c(38L, 57L, 50L, 46L, 56L, 32L, 39L, 28L,
              39L, 58L, 37L),
      job = c(
        "technician",
        "retired",
        "management",
        "technician",
        "admin.",
        "services",
        "blue-collar",
        "technician",
        "management",
        "management",
        "technician"
      ),
      marital = c(
        "married",
        "married",
        "married",
        "single",
        "married",
        "single",
        "single",
        "single",
        "married",
        "married",
        "married"
      ),
      education = c(
        "secondary",
        "secondary",
        "secondary",
        "secondary",
        "secondary",
        "tertiary",
        "tertiary",
        "tertiary",
        "tertiary",
        "tertiary",
        "secondary"
      ),
      default = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no",
                  "no", "no", "no"),
      balance = c(
        1442L,
        718L,
        268L,
        4367L,
        3554L,
        785L,
        48L,
        3623L,
        5142L,
        2261L,
        6384L
      ),
      housing = c("yes",
                  "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
      loan = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no",
               "no", "no", "yes"),
      contact = c(
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular",
        "cellular"
      ),
      day = c(3L, 3L, 3L,
              3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      month = c(
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun",
        "jun"
      ),
      duration = c(113L, 170L, 74L, 65L, 151L, 273L, 539L, 138L,
                   157L, 1361L, 254L),
      campaign = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                   1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
      pdays = c(119L,-1L, 90L, 96L,-1L,-1L,-1L, 85L,-1L, 391L, 96L),
      previous = c(1L, 0L, 2L,
                   1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L),
      poutcome = c(
        "failure",
        "unknown",
        "failure",
        "failure",
        "unknown",
        "unknown",
        "unknown",
        "success",
        "unknown",
        "failure",
        "failure"
      ),
      Target = c("no",
                 "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no")
    ),
    row.names = 40000:40010,
    class = "data.frame"
  )


    
    
data1<-bank_data2
data1$Target<-ifelse(data1$Target=="yes",1,0)
data1 <- dummy_cols(data1, select_columns = c('job','marital','education','default','housing','loan','contact','month','poutcome'))
data1<-select(data1,-'job',-'marital',-'education',-'default',-'housing',-'loan',-'contact',-'month',-'poutcome')


#Stage 2 Rescaling
#Rescaling
# Function for scaling
normalize = function(x){ 
  return ((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))) 
} 
str(data1)


bank_data_n<-as.data.frame(lapply(data1, normalize))

data1$Target<-as.factor(data1$Target)


bank_data2<-data1
bank_data2<-select(bank_data2,"poutcome_failure","poutcome_other","poutcome_success",
                   "duration","poutcome_unknown","Target")
str(bank_data2)
set.seed(2810)  # to make reproducible results
length<-length(bank_data2$Target)  #45211
45211*0.8 #36168.8

train_obs = sample(1:length, size=length*0.8, replace=FALSE)
bank_train<-bank_data2[train_obs, !(names(bank_data2) %in% "Target")]
bank_train<-data.frame(bank_train)
bank_test<-bank_data2[-train_obs, !(names(bank_data2) %in% "Target")]
bank_test<-data.frame(bank_test)

train_bank_results<-bank_data2[train_obs, "Target"]
test_bank_results<-bank_data2[-train_obs, "Target"]
length(train_bank_results) #36168 rows
length(test_bank_results) #9043 rows



knn_pred_n<-knn(bank_train,bank_test,train_bank_results,k=1)

sqrt(length(bank_data2$age))  #212  #~ 211 need odd number 
knn_pred_n<-knn(bank_train,bank_test,train_bank_results,k=211)


CrossTable(x =test_bank_results,y =knn_pred_n ,prop.chisq = FALSE,prop.c = F,prop.t = F,prop.r = F)


library(pROC)

knn_pred_n_roc<-ifelse(knn_pred_n==1,1,0)
table(knn_pred_n_roc)

rocCurve_KNN <- roc(test_bank_results, knn_pred_n_roc, direction = "<", levels = c(0,1))

plot(rocCurve_KNN, col="red", main='ROC KNN',percent = TRUE,add=FALSE, asp = NA)
```

Comment: Try `par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))`. Also try dragging your plotting window to make it larger.

Comment: perfect , I reduce the margin by the above and increase the plot size

Comment: This is not reproducibe: `Error in dummy_cols(data1, select_columns = c("job", "marital", "education",  : 
  could not find function "dummy_cols"`. Where did you load this function from?

Comment: library(fastDummies)  , I probably missed it

Comment: rocCurve_KNN <- roc(test_bank_results_roc, knn_pred_n_roc, direction = "<", levels = c(0,1))
rocCurve_tree <- roc(test_bank_results_roc, bank_type_pred3_roc, direction = "<", levels = c(0,1))

par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
x11(width = 20, height = 4)
plot(rocCurve_KNN, col="red", main='ROC curve',percent = TRUE,add=FALSE, asp = NA,legacy.axes = TRUE)

plot.roc(rocCurve_tree, percent = TRUE, main="ROC", col="#1c61b6", add=T,asp = NA,legacy.axes = TRUE)
legend("topright", legend=c("KNN", "Tree with cost error"),
       col=c("red", "#1c61b6"), lty=1, cex=0.8)